# Oracle sql - Expressão não encontrada

Tags: sql, query, oracle

O que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte:
Liste os nomes dos CDs que tenham preço de venda maior que 10,00 reais ou a gravadora seja a de código 3, ordenados por ordem alfabética decrescente dos nomes dos CDs. Exibir os nomes dos CDs em iniciando com a letra maiúscula.

E fiz a seguinte query:

```
SELECT INITCAP(CD_NOME) FROM CD
INNER JOIN GRAVADORA ON CD.GRAV_CODIGO = GRAVADORA.GRAV_CODIGO AND CD_PRECO_VENDA > 10 OR GRAV_CODIGO = 3
ORDER BY DESC CD_NOME;
```

Porém, está apresentando o seguinte erro:

> ORA-00936: expressão não encontrada

O que estou fazendo de errado? :(

Comment: O erro (sem entrar na solução) é no order by , coloque o ORDER BY 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, sem verificar a estrutura das tabelas envolvidas fica difícil, mas pelo que li e entendi, deve ficar assim:

```
SELECT INITCAP(CD.NOME) FROM CD INNER JOIN GRAVADORA ON CD.GRAV_CODIGO = GRAVADORA.GRAV_CODIGO WHERE CD.PRECO_VENDA > 10 OR GRAVADORA.GRAV_CODIGO = 3 ORDER BY CD.NOME DESC ;
```

Espero ter ajudado.